# Should the answer to "How old do you think Peter is?" be a prediction or a conclusion?

Tags: exam-questions

> "How old do you think Peter is?"
> "I just looked at his driver's license. He ___ 33."
> A. might be
> B. may be
> C. must be
> D. should be

Should the answer to this question be a prediction or a conclusion since the character in this question have already looked at Peter's driver license

Comment: Presumably the licence gives Peter's date of birth. The speaker has done a quick calculation - "If he was born in 1987 he must be 33 now."

Comment: If you see someone's date of birth & know their age for a certainty, I would say "is" rather than "must be". "Must be" is the type of thing I'd use for an estimation, where I feel I've a high degree of certainty but still not 100% — "I remember going to his 30th birthday party a few years ago, I had just come back from America on holidays & was still jetlagged. That was 2018, so he must be 33".

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the preceding sentence; '*I just looked at his driver's license*'. The subsequent sentence '*He ____ 33*' is therefore implicitly dependent on the conclusions derived from the first. Put another way, you could write it thusly:

> '*I just looked at his driver's license; he ___ 33*'.

See [here](https://www.theschoolrun.com/what-is-a-semi-colon) for more information on the semicolon if unsure.

To answer your question, a date of birth is commonly included on a [driver's](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/sites/default/files/images/current-full-front.jpg) [licence](https://dmv.ny.gov/sites/default/files/resize/styles/panopoly_image_original/public/old_dl_for_sample_docs-653x325.png), thus the answer must be a conclusion.

Comment: So, is it must be or should be

Comment: The answer would be C. The licence provides complete information; should would indicate relative but not completely surety in your answer, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

More than a prediction or a conclusion, I would give it the technical name of ***deduction***, which [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deduction) defines it as:

> UNCOUNTABLE NOUN Deduction is the process of reaching a conclusion
> about something because of other things that you know to be true.
>
> - ...a
>   case that tested his powers of deduction.

I said "technical" because here "must" is the correct ***[modal of deduction](https://englishpost.org/modals-of-deduction)*** to be used:

> We use ***must*** when we feel sure that something is true because there’s very strong evidence.
>
> - Her son is at university so she ***must be*** at least 40.

In your sentence, however, ***must*** may express also a slight uncertainty in the character's ability to calculate quickly and correctly by looking of the date on Peter's driving licence:

> He ***must be*** 33, if my calculation is right.

***Might*** and ***may*** can also be used for deductions, but they mean rather that we think something is possible but we’re not sure.

> I heard a noise, there ***might be*** a cat on the roof.

In your sentence, the evidence of the truth is clear, so we are not predicting, but making a deduction which is ***sure*** to be true. ***Should*** is used to show when something is likely or expected, and it does not apply here, because something which is certainly true cannot ***be likely to be true***.